# hyphen key in Excel somehow is remapped

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel: how to disable extend selection mode (F8 key) being activated by “-” key?](https://superuser.com/questions/37157/excel-how-to-disable-extend-selection-mode-f8-key-being-activated-by-key)

For one single user on the server, when she in Excel, and uses the hyphen on the number pad, it acts as if F8 (Extend Selection) is pressed.  I have tried several keyboards and computers, and it is just this one user.
I have tried other templates to rule out a corrupted template, tried other programs and have had no problems.
This is driving me crazy and this is an accountant so she needs to use the number pad extensively.  This just started happening all of a sudden today.

We are using MS Office 2007

HELP!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/37157/excel-how-to-disable-extended-mode-activated-by-key

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the cause, but you could use [Key Tweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) to put it back how you want it. I don't think there'd be any network/user issues?

Comment: Hmmm, and then put it back to what...?

Comment: Remap hyphen as hyphen!